# Why would one see light from the innermost part of an underwater cave?

Tags: scuba-diving, flashlights, cave-diving

During the [Cova dels Arquets diving disaster](https://cavedivingaccident.com/trapped-in-darkness-the-harrowing-tale-of-the-cova-dels-arquets-cave/), Ricard and Denisio went into the innermost part of the cave because they saw light coming from there.

[image]

Why would there have been light coming from there? There would obviously have been no sunlight. Was it somehow light from their flashlights being reflected?

Comment: I am not sure, but when I skimmed through the link you shared, none of it indicated that they went after the light they saw once they were in.

Comment: my guess is this is what they were referring to: "A glimmer of hope emerged as they caught sight of a hairline crack in the ceiling above. The faintest hint of light seeped through, beckoning them to investigate further. Fueled by a combination of desperation and determination, they swam toward the crack, their hearts pounding with anticipation. In a daring act of desperation, Ricard and Denisio made a risky gamble, deciding to squeeze through the unknown crack, oblivious to where it would lead them."